# Stacking Non-Sibling Elements in CSS

Tags: css

I have some HTML code produced from a script which draws an interactive tree like [this one](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/43a860bc0024792f8803bba8ca0d5ecd):

```
<svg width="1200" height="500">
    <g class="node" transform="translate(0, 242.3076934814453)">
        <circle class = "node" />
        <foreignobject class = "preview" />
    </g>
    <g class="node" transform="translate(0, 242.3076934814453)">
        <circle class = "node" />
        <foreignobject class = "preview" />
    </g>
    <g class="node" transform="translate(0, 242.3076934814453)">
        <circle class = "node" />
        <foreignobject class = "preview" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

And so on (there are many more `<g class="node">` children of the parent `<svg>`). The `<foreignobject>` is an element meant to represent a preview box that is displayed upon hovering on the node. In some cases, the area occupied by the preview box when shown will overlap with the `<circle>` element from another node. In this case, I would like the preview to be stacked on top of any circle element, but I haven't been able to find a solution that is able to represent stacking relationships amongst elements that do not share the same direct parent (e.g. `z-index`). I'm looking for a solution that would not require me to restructure the relationships between these HTMl elements. Currently, it seems as if the some of the `foreignobject`s are actually under the `circle`s of the other nodes.

Ideally, I would be able to specify some property(ies) like `z-index` in the CSS for `preview` and `node.circle` that would yield the desired behavior. Of course, if this is too optimistic, I would still like to know what a working solution could look like. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Z-index doesn't need the same direct parent. By default everything on the page is inside `<body>`

```
body{ z-index: 0}               /* by default */
nav{ z-index: 1}                /* it puts <nav> above the <body> */
div{ z-index: -1}               /* it puts <div> below, behind the <body> */
```

It was just for your info as I think you are looking for `position` not `z-index`, I believe you need something like this:

```
g:hover::after{ position: absolute; content: '*foreignobject*'}
    /* if foreignobject can be putted into css...  or simpler: */
g:hover foreignobject{ position: absolute; height: 50vh; width: 50vw}
```

Css `content` has limitations, it's not HTML, if `foreignobject` is an image or plain text you are in luck!
The `::before` and `::after` elements can be displayed with more complicated relations - look at the snippet, ugly but simple
`position` can have co-ordinates `top` `bottom` `right` `left` relative to main parent - `<body>` or (if exists) nearest parent with `position`. Usual it is used as:
`parent{ position: relative}` without any co-ordinates just to set it as a parent for `absolute, relative, fixed` children.

```css
body{ text-align: center}
div{ background: yellow; width: 200px;}
p{ font: normal 14px verdana, sans-serif}
div:hover p::after{ content: "I'm big red css \A div:hover p::after \A"; font: normal bold 42px time, serif; background: red; width: 100vw; position: absolute; top: 50vh; padding: 100px; display: block; white-space: pre}
```

```html
<div><p>paragraph</p></div>
```